# How to find the full path (and then open using python pillow) of a file in the Download folder of an Android device?

Tags: python, android, python-imaging-library

This question can be broken down into 2 sub-problems:
**First, I need to get the "global"/"absolute" full path of a file (that I downloaded manually from the Internet) on Android**
**Second, I need to be able to load the file (it is `.png`) using pillow**

For the first problem, the main difficulty is figuring out what the file path truly is so that I can open the file. If there is some way to open the file *without* using the file path (so just the name), that would work too. I would like to also be able to write files to the same directory, but that is not necessary.
For the second problem, I'm assuming it would be similar to opening a file on Windows. This is what I mean:

```py
mT = Image.open(rf"C:\Users\visha\OneDrive\Desktop\ArnavsThings\BoardGameBot\mt.png")
```

Using that method on Windows gives me a new object `mT` that stores an `Image` object with data about `mt.png`. I want to be able to replace the path with a new path on Android to do accomplish the same task. Would using the same code with a different path work on Android, or is there a different function/method to use that would be better?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is unclear about which file you are talking.

Comment: I want to take a .png file that is on Android and then open it using pillow. I can put the file anywhere I want. The image is something that I downloaded onto the Android phone, and now want to use python and pillow to open - meaning that the image is a personal file that does not come with Android. For example, the file could be a random meme from the internet or it could be a picture of my face, but it is not an app's icon.

Comment: `I can put the file anywhere I want. ` Yes  true. Well then you know the path i would say. If you create a file you need to provide a full path.(well mostly). So your question is very strange.

Comment: I don't understand - How does the Android file system even work? I know that in Windows, you can copy the path from the file explorer. Is there some way to do the same thing on Android? **I don't know how to provide a full path** because I **don't know the full path**

Comment: For further clarification, I am downloading the file *from the Internet*. I am not creating a file; rather, I am trying to find the file that I downloaded, using Python. I need Python to 'see' the file and then to be able to open that file. To do so, I need the full path, which I don't know how to get.

Comment: If you download a file from internet then a copy of that file is created on your Android device. Now tell to which directory you downloaded. Also tell how the download was done. Show your download code.

Comment: It seems I may have found the answer, but still have no clue if this is the correct way to do it. If the file is in the "Download" folder, then the file path would be `/storage/emulated/0/Download/Foobar.png`. Please tell me if this is the "correct" file path.

Comment: I'm not downloading using code - I am downloading using my fingers. I go to Chrome, search up "meme", long-hold the image, click "Download image", and then find the image I just downloaded in the "Download" folder. The image's title is "download.jpeg"

Comment: You could have told that at the start of your post. And then have asked full path of Download folder instead of `How to find the file path?`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233986/discussion-between-arnav-poddar-and-blackapps).

Comment: You can try to use pythons built in os library to explore the fs.

Comment: The path you mentioned for the Download folder is the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @blackapps for confirming what I thought might be the correct answer.
**The answer to part 1:** Any file stored in the Download folder on Android will have the path `/storage/emulated/0/Download/filename.fileextension`
**The answer to part 2:** To open a file using pillow, the code above will function on both Windows and Android.

Comment: No hard coded paths. The Download folder can be obtained by code. Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment_DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).